# Intersection of subsets is a single point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> **Theorem:**  Let $\{E_n\}$ be a family of closed, non-empty and limited subsets of a complete metric space $(X,d)$. If $E_n\supset E_{n+1}$ and
>   $\text{diam}(E_n)\rightarrow 0$ show that  $$\cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}
>  E_n$$ is a single point.

Some definitions are

> We say a metric space is complete if every Cauchy sequence converges.
>   A sequence is Cauchy if eventually the terms in the sequence get
>   arbitrarily close to each other ([definition of a complete metric space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198947/definition-of-a-complete-metric-space)).

The diameter definition

> If $E\subset X$, $E\neq \emptyset$ and $S$ is such that
>   $$S=\{d(p,q)\quad;\quad p,q \in E\}$$ then $diam(E)=\sup S$

How I can proof this?

What I think is

If $E_n$ is complete then $d(x_n,x_{n+1})\rightarrow 0$ right? It's already doesn't means that the sequence is a single point?

Comment: [You can find a proof here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiDh9OayLHUAhUFqY8KHRCIDyQQygQIJzAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCantor%2527s_intersection_theorem%23Variant_in_complete_metric_spaces&usg=AFQjCNGWRBJ0md06H_V3OzqRBP9Xrm14_g&sig2=NNOesGNqbiClmrlEryIasA)

Comment: The usual term in English for "limited" in this context is "bounded". And in your last sentence, what you mean to ask is "that the sequence converges to  to a single point".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pick $x_n \in E_n $. Looking at sequence $\{x_n\},$ it is clear that $x_n ,x_{m} \in E_n$, for all $m > n$ So $d(x_n,x_{m}) \leq diam(E_n) \rightarrow 0.$ Therefore , $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy sequence in $X$ an so it converges to a point, say $x \in X$. Further $x \in  E$ since for all $m \in N$ the sequence $\{x_n\}$ eventually lies in $E_m$ and $E_m$ is closed.

Furthermore,  $diam(\cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} E_n ) \leq diam(E_n) \rightarrow 0.$ So $diam(\cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} E_n ) = 0$ which implies $\cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} E_n=\{x\}$

Comment: My edit was just to add the missing dollar signs around \{x_n\} in the first line.............. BTW you can use " \to" for "$\to$" instead of "\rightarrow", which is less typing.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet  thanks for edit, and   useful tip  !

Comment: Another one is \|v\| for $\|v\|$ which looks better than ||x||, which gives $||x||$, especially  when you have to write the product of two of them, as \|x\|\cdot \|y\| gives $\|x\|\cdot \|y\|$, which  is easier to read than $||x|| \cdot ||y||.$.... MathJax has some oddities: $\nabla$, pronounced "del", is \nabla.